# What do the PNP transistors in a 741 differential pair do?

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential, differential-amplifier, 741-opamp

I am working on a project using the internal circuitry of LM741 op-amp and I've found its differential pair quite interesting.

[image]

Mostly its NPN to PNP input. I've searched it to see what it does but couldn't find any specific information. I've be trying to simulate a circuit with it both and without the PNPs but the output is either something good or nothing at all. Can someone explain?

Edit: I've added the schematic of the circuit I am trying to build.  It is a square wave generator using a capacitor charging and discharging.

Here is a simplified version of the LM741 where VCC is 2.5 V and VSS is -2.5 V:

[image]

Comment: It will be easier to see what the transistors are doing if your drawing shows more of the context. Few of us know the internals of the 741 off by heart, or want to go and look them up. Show the entire +ve to -ve rail circuitry, and label what the inputs and outputs are of the section you've sliced out.

Comment: Ok I will add the full schematic

Comment: I suggest that you read: https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/62723054/Ryhma5_Ele4.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1329665985000&api=v2

Comment: I also found out this pdf but it is very basic, I want a more complex understanding if possible... for example there is no information for the npn to pnp part

Comment: As no one here designed the 741, we can only **guess** why the circuit is like it is. My guess is that one of the reasons is that this circuit allows for an NPN input pair (Q1, Q2) while getting the output at the bottom side (collector of Q5). The designer(s) could have chosen this for better performance (generally NPNs have better perfomance than PNPs). But this is just my (educated) guess, there might be more/other reasons.

Comment: Thinking out loud here. It's almost cascode-like, but Q1/2 are common collector, so there's no Miller to overcome. If you want to most of the business at negative rail with NPNs (Q7,8,12,16) then you need PNPs in your input to get currents from your input common mode voltage down to neg rail. So that's **why** Q5/6 and PNPs. They can't be on the input though because Miller would hammer the bandwidth. So Q1/2 are there. And I guess Q1/2 are better transistors built in NPN rather than PNP.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer but now I have another question. With what can replace those PNP-s so I can simplify my circuit? I've tried with resistors and my output was quite the same but my duty was more like 60 to 40 not 50% and I have a spike on my lower pulse, I can show you a picture to see it better if needed

Comment: You can simplify the circuit, simply try to use the PNP diff pair instead. Look at this  example http://www.douglas-self.com/ampins/dipa/dpafig1.gif

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of Q5 and Q6 is to act as level shifters to refer the signal to the negative rail so an NPN transistor can be used as the main voltage amplifying stage (VAS, Q15).

In the late 1960's when the 741 was designed it was not possible to implement well-performing PNP transistors as they had to be implemented as lateral devices with low Hfe and Ft. Parts of the circuit that need high-performance were implemented with NPNs.

Normally an NPN differential pair input would mean that the output was referred to the positive rail and would need a PNP in the VAS.

By implementing it as shown the VAS (Q15)can be an NPN. Q5 and Q6 merely need to act as common base devices to transfer the currents from the differential input stage to the current mirror Q7/Q8 and the input of Q15. They do not need to be high-performance devices.

Later, similar, integrated circuits such as the LM324/358 used PNPs in the input stage, by that time it was possible to create better monolithic PNPs.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a pretty minimal solution.

[image: Modified 741 op amp]

To make the op amp more stable and reduce the overshoot increase the value of R5 or C1 (or both) but doing either will slow the edges down.

**EDIT1**

Managed to simplify it a bit further. Not much left of the 741 design though.
[image: Square wave generator]

**EDIT2**

[image: Modified square generator]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem the only thing that matter is that it works, thank you very much for your answer but I have one question. I wanted to use npn, not pnp's at the diff pair but seems to not work, can you explain me why is that?

Comment: @PowerTb321 To have npn diff pair input transistors the whole design needs to be turned upside down and swap most of the other npns for pnps and vice-a-versa. See edit.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! But in termes of efficiency / protection witch version is better?

Comment: @PowerTb321 I'm not sure what you mean by "efficiency / protection".

Comment: I mean why use npn or pnp as input, is there any advantage?

Comment: @PowerTb321 I'm not aware of any particular advantage of one over the other. There are commercially available op amps in each variety. An example of an op amp with pnp input transistors would be the common LM358. If you have a look at the Philips Semiconductors LM358 data sheet it shows the internal equivalent circuit.

Comment: @PowerTb321 - when the 741 was designed high-performance PNP transistors were not possible so NPNs were used where high-performance was needed. The LM358 was designed a few years later.